# Energy function of a RBM

Tags: restricted-boltzmann-machine

My question is simply why the Energy function of a RBM is given by:

$$E = -\sum_{i,j} w_{ij} \, v_i \, h_j -\sum_i \alpha_i \, v_i - \sum_i \beta_i \, h_i$$

when the energy of the Boltzmann Machine is given by:

$$ E = -\Biggl(\sum_{i<j}w_{ij}s_is_j + \sum_ib_is_i\Biggl) $$

Does the first is derived from the second when the interactions of the nodes are restricted to be only with nodes of a different layer? I searched but I couldn't find an answer. The formula for the Energy of the RBM are always given in that form.